# preg_replace para substituir espaços por traços

Tags: php

Preciso pegar o título de uma notícia e exibir na URL. Para tal, quero buscar o titulo no banco de dados e substituir cada espaço em branco entre uma palavra e outra, por uma hífen. Por exemplo: "Teste de noticia" ficaria "Teste-de-noticia".

Eu tentei:

```
$titulo_novo = preg_replace('<\W+>', "-", $titulo); 

//$titulo é o titulo vindo do banco de dados
```

Comment: O que já tentou? Tem alguma parte do código que gostaria de mostrar para ajudar a resolver seu problema? Aumente o conteúdo da pergunta e terá respostas mais especificas ;)

Comment: Eu tentei:  $titulo_novo = preg_replace('<\W+>', "-", $titulo); 
//$titulo é o titulo vindo do banco de dados.

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando essa nova informação amigo

Comment: tente assim `$titulo_novo = preg_replace('/[ -]+/' , '-' , $titulo);`

Comment: Consegui. Só gerou um erro: caracteres acentuados (ã, ó, etc) precisam estar normais, por exemplo, substituir á por a ; ção por cao...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é bem simples utilizando `preg_replace`. Caso quisesse apenas colocar o título como URL convertendo espaços para hifens, bastaria apenas adicionar:

```
$titulo_novo = preg_replace('/[ -]+/' , '-' , $titulo);
```

Mas caso queira algo completo que remova e converta também os acentos, poderá usar:

```
$titulo = "Notícia Com Ácêntös";
$titulo_novo = strtolower( preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "-", 
strtr(utf8_decode(trim($titulo)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),
"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );

echo $titulo_novo; //pode remover essa linha, é só pra mostrar como ficou.
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado Victor Gomes!

Comment: O `ereg_*` foi depreciado, troca lá por `preg_replace()` :P

Comment: obrigado @rray, corrigido ;)